# Entity Framework и UWP

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Здесь описан простой пример реализации БД в приложении UWP http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html

Пара вопрос для тех кто работал EF:

- Быстрее ли он чем обычный SQLite UWP wrapper?
- В примере источником данных является модель, что если там будет очень много записей, работает ли по умолчанию виртуализация, нужно ли создавать ViewModel для реализации всего перечисленного?
- Как она ведет себя на мобильных устройствах при больших БД (10K+)?

Comment: Никогда EF не может быть быстрее прямого обращения к базе, т.к. у него, помимо непосредственно mapping, ещё куча всякой «бухгалтерии»

Comment: @ixSci У меня стоит примерно такая задача: Есть два класса, один из них содержит ссылку на другой (по `ID`). Необходимо при выборке по этому `ID` вывести `Title`. Сейчас я использую db.Get<>, но когда элементов много то времени это занимает соответственно. Решит ли трабл EF нормально настроить Relations?

Comment: Все вопросы производительности решаются одним способом — измерениями. Ничего нельзя сказать наверняка, пока ты не полностью погружён в задачу и имеешь под рукой данные по производительности, а также понимаешь, где загвоздка.

Comment: @ixSci А вообще на сколько я понял из документации, я могу из поля ссылки одного класса сослаться на другой класс (и соответственно все его поля)? или я не правильно что то понял?

Comment: Ссылаться можно, это просто создаст связь в таблице, EF не делает никакой магии, это просто фреймворк для облегчения работы. Использовать его для ускорения было бы неправильно.